# Pwoli.js - How to get pagination info in API response?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm getting a response like this from an API setup with pwoli.js

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Company - 1",
        "status": 1,
        "description": "Company = 1 description",
        "phone": null,
        "email": "email@company1.com",
        "website": "",
        "eventId": 3,
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "myGetter": "EVENT - 3"
    },
    ...
]
```

I want to get the pagination info like, current page, total count, total pages etc. to implement pagination.

Please help me on how to do this?

Pagination data in API response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a line like below before `Pwoli.respond(...)`:

```
Pwoli.serializer.collectionEnvelope = 'companies';
```

Your response will be enveloped with key 'companies' and all the additional meta information will now be available in the response body itself.